# PHP Database not updating with correct values

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am trying to update the database to show my "image id" and my "tagging id" however, every time an image and "tag" is selected it only updates it with "1" and not the corresponding "id" for the image and the tags.

This is the code that I am using to get variables.

```
  echo "<input type ='hidden' name ='id' value = '{$row['image']}'>";
```

This is the table that is displayed after running the SQL query:

```
echo "<td>";
echo "<select name ='dropdown'> 
    <option value='1'>dog</option>
    <option value='2'>cat</option>
    <option value='3'>dark</option>
    <option value='4'>light</option>
</select>"."</td>";
echo"<td>".'<input type="submit" name="tag" value="insertTag">'."</td>";
```

When the button is clicked the following is executed:

```
if(isset($_POST['tag'])){ 
        $idpic= $_POST['id'];

    $selectbox = $_POST['dropdown'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO table3(ID ,PicutureID, IDtag)
VALUES('','.$idpic.','.$selectbox .')"; 

$runquery = mysql_query($sql) or die("<b>Error:</b> <br/>" . mysql_error());
```

How come every time for example "cat" is selected table 3 "IDtag" remains as 1 and also similarly the "PicutreID" does not correspond either.

Thanks for the help

Comment: By the way, if you're updating the database, why not just use the UPDATE SET command?

Comment: Try `echo`ing the `$sql` to make sure that it's actually generating the statement that you hope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, I think the field name (PictureID) mentioned in the query is misspelt.

If that is not the case, lets look at the concatenation in the query because it seems to be a little messy. It could be done in two ways.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table3(ID ,PicutureID, IDtag) 
         VALUES('','".$idpic."','".$selectbox ."')";
```

If the above query seems confusing you could enclose the variables within curly braces and write the complete code in one go within one set of double quotes.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table3(ID ,PicutureID, IDtag) 
        VALUES ('','{$idpic}','{$selectbox }')";
```

Try these and let me know.

Comment: What is the output you get when you echo the query ($sql)?

Comment: If you feel that the line where $idpic is initialised is the cause of the problem then check the value of $row['image']

Comment: @Adrash Thanks Adrash, the error was because I had a form outside the whileloo[ and I moved it to the inside of the loop and it works now, thanks again :)

Comment: If it helped you out and proved to be useful I would request you to upvote it, that would be a real Thank you for me.

Answer (score 0):

The following

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table3(ID ,PicutureID, IDtag)
VALUES('','.$idpic.','.$selectbox .')";
```

should be as

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table3(ID ,PicutureID, IDtag)
VALUES('','".$idpic."','".$selectbox ."')";
```

OR

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table3(ID ,PicutureID, IDtag)
VALUES('','$idpic','$selectbox')";
```

Comment: @Abfik Chakraborty, Sorry pal still the same error:(, The database still always show it as 1 for the image and the tagging. It doesn't update to the corresponding number. I have a feeling its something to with the code here
`code`$idpic= $_POST['id'];

    $selectbox = $_POST['dropdown'];
`code`